# Getting a 400 for my AFNetworking get call

Tags: swift, afnetworking, foursquare

I am using AFNetworking for the first time and attempting to make a get call using the FourSquare Places API. When I test with the endpoint on FourSquare's documentation website, my url with params works, but not with AFNetworking code. I keep getting a 400.

```
func findCoffee(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore"
    let params = [
        "ll": "\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)",
        "intent": intent,
        "limit": limit,
        "client_id": "\(clientId)",
        "client_secret": "\(clientSecret)"
    ]

    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()

    manager.get(url, parameters: params, success: { (operation, responseObject) in

    }) { (operation, error) in

    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks fine. Can you check on Postman and if that works you need to compare your request and url with working one.

Comment: @May yang this is suggestion. Use alamofire. Because you are using swift

Comment: You need `v=YYYYMMDD` param.